# Problema con claves primarias

Tags: php, sql

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de noticias que permite que el usuario haga comentarios debajo.

Esta es mi tabla de noticias, **tiene un campo "comments_id" que se relaciona con la tabla tabla_comments con el comments_id**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_news` (
  `id_new` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_new` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `subtitile_new` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `data_new` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `description_new` TEXT NULL,
  `id_image_new` INT(11) NULL,
  `id_category` INT(11) NULL,
  `comments_id` INT(11) NULL,
  `id_user` INT(11) NULL,
  `typenew` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_new`, `id_category`, `comments_id`, `id_user`, `id_image_new`),
  INDEX `id_category_idx` (`id_category` ASC),
  INDEX `id_image_new_idx` (`id_image_new` ASC),
  INDEX `comments_id_idx` (`comments_id` ASC),
  INDEX `id_user_idx` (`id_user` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `id_category`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_category`)
    REFERENCES `table_category` (`id_category`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `id_image_new`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_image_new`)
    REFERENCES `table_images` (`id_image_new`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `comments_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`comments_id`)
    REFERENCES `table_comments` (`id_comment`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `id_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`)
    REFERENCES `table_comments` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Esta es mi tabla de comentatios

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_comments` (
  `id_comment` INT(11) NULL,
  `comments_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT(11) NULL,
  `data_comment` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_comment`),
  INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `user_table` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Que esta tabla de comentarios se relaciona con la de usuarios

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_table` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_user` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
  `lastname_user` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
  `user_type` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Por que quiero que una noticia tenga mas de un comentario, entonces la noticia con id 1, tiene comentario/s con ID = 1 ( pero mas de un comentario tiene un id 1 ), con lo que estarian relacionado con la noticia 1.**

El problema surge que me tira el siguiente error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\php\class\User.Class.php:89
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\php\class\User.Class.php(89): PDOStatement-&gt;execute()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\php\data\commentUser.php(34): User-&gt;publicarComentario('1', 'fdsfsddf', '1')
#2 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\php\class\User.Class.php</b> on line <b>89</b><br />
```

**Muchas gracias**

Comment: Al poner una columna `comments_id` en la tabla de noticias estás diciendo en teoría que *una noticia sólo puede tener un comentario*, por lo tanto, tienes que  hacerlo al revés, o sea, expresar la relación en `table_comments`, agregando allí una columna `id_new` y creando la restricción allí. Así, cada comentario quedará ligado a la noticia a que pertenece. @David te ha explicado en su acertada respuesta lo que tienes que hacer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como los comentarios dependen de la noticia, y no al revés, no puedes poner la clave ajena `FK` en noticias, sino en los comentarios. Tal y como lo tienes, para regsitrar una noticia, debes contar con un comentario previo y, en consecuencia, no puedes tener más de un comentario por noticia.

Elimina de `table_news` este código:

```
CONSTRAINT `comments_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`comments_id`)
    REFERENCES `table_comments` (`id_comment`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

Y añade el homólogo en `table_comments`:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`id_new`)
  REFERENCES `table_news` (`id_new`)
```

Añadiendo previamente el campo `id_new` en la tabla `table_comments`.

```
ALTER TABLE table_comments ADD id_new INT;
```

Te recomiendo que revises el modelo ER de Chen y verás con mucha más claridad este tipo de cuestiones.

Comment: Me solucionastes el problema, muchisimas gracias!.